# whmcs phone verify hook

Tags: hook, whmcs

I write a costume phone verification module for WHMCS

and i used the following hook to redirect clients to verification module before they check out their order.

```php
   add_hook('ShoppingCartValidateCheckout', 1, "PV");

   function PV($vars) {
   $clientID = intval($_SESSION['uid']);
   $isVerified = //check from database
   if ($isVerified != 'true') {

            return '<a href="index.php?m=module">send code</a>';
        }
```

this hook works fine when client is logged in  but for new clients that register in page cart.php?a=view this hook not work because  $_SESSION['uid'] returns 0 . which hook should i use for the above exception?

Comment: All data that you want is in $vars Variable: `$userid=$vars['userid'];
    $firstname=$vars['firstname'];
    $lastname=$vars['lastname'];
    //loginemail,email, country-calling-code-phonenumber,phonenumber,
    //companyname, address1,address2 , city,state,postcode, ..etc
    //file_put_contents("C:/xampp_my/htdocs/my/sss.txt",var_export($vars,true));
    if(empty($userid))
    {
   //Notlogin , check the data
    }`

Comment: For those not logged in clients, make a session variable to save isVerified. once they register after checkout, save the value to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved by using the following hook

```
add_hook('ClientLogin', 1, function($vars) {
// Perform hook code here...
});
```